# how to use a variable for directory path in find command in unix

Tags: shell-script

I need to know how to use a variable to pass directory name in Find command.
I am using below command but its not working.

```
while read -r directory file ;do
  echo "$directory"---this command works $HOME/data
  echo "$file"
  x="$(find $directory -type f -name "$file" -mtime -1 -printf "%f\n")"--not working
  echo $x
done < "$HOME/static_data.txt"
```

I want to pass directory and file name through loop.but for directory it gives me error saying

```
'$HOME/data' no such file or directory
```

whereas I can see the directory.

Comment: What is the output of `echo "$directory"`?  Does it literally say `$HOME/data` or is `HOME` being expanded?  Also you seem to be missing a quote at the end on the `done < "$HOME/static_data.txt` line

Comment: Also what is that random `f` doing in your `find` command?  I have a feeling you have not pasted the code into this question exactly as it is being executed on your system.

Comment: Yes it says $HOME/data and yes while pasting the code here one < "$HOME/static_data.txt" I missed it..But its there in the actual code.

Comment: x="$(find $directory -type f -name "$file" -mtime -1 -printf "%f\n")"

Comment: So what you're saying is you have not pasted the code exactly?  Your question **does not** contain `-type`.  Also please edit the question instead of adding changes in comments

Comment: I have made the changes in the question..Can you now tell me what needs to be done to get the code work?

Answer (score 1):

While your `echo "$directory"` command "works" it does not expand `$HOME`, nor do subsequent uses of `$directory`.

The directory you want **is not** `$HOME/data`, that directory doesn't exist (literally).  What you want is the expansion of `$HOME` (probably something like `/home/user313150/data`).

You can overcome this by using `eval` although I would recommend finding another solution as eval can be dangerous.

```
while read -r directory file; do
  directory=$(eval echo "$directory")
  echo "$directory"
  echo "$file"
  x="$(find "$directory" -type f -name "$file" -mtime -1 -printf "%f\n")"
  echo $x
done < "$HOME/static_data.txt"
```

Comment: Link to the related discussion: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96935/discussion-on-answer-by-jesse-b-how-to-use-a-variable-for-directory-path-in-find

Comment: I changed the static data entry and then my code worked.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the syntax problems outlined by Jesse_b, your `$HOME/static_data.txt` file which serves as input for the `while` loop, contains entries with variables.
The problem with this is when entering the loop is that the `$HOME` is not expanded when `$directory` is.

A possible solution could be as follows.

```
while read -r directory file ;do
  echo "$directory"
  echo "$file"
  x="$(find "$directory" -type f -name "$file" -mtime -1 -printf "%f\n")"
  echo "$x"
done <<<"$( envsubst < "$HOME/static_data.txt" )"
```

The `envsubst` is taking care of expanding `$HOME` before passing it to the while loop.